# XML dp different from computed dp (dip)

Tags: android, xamarin

In my xml I have this on a TextView:

`android:textSize="18dp"` (yes I know dp is not preferable for text, but that's beside the point)

I have some other TextViews that I'm creating programmatically, and I'm setting the TextSize as such:

```
view.TextSize = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 18, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
```

However, the latter text size (the one created programmatically) appears to be a lot larger than the XML version. I'm wondering why? :)

Comment: see my answer with value define in dimens.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize); because the documentation of the getDimension method states that it returns a Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric. which I understand to be the precalculated absolute px value.

That is, use:

```
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_small));
```

Comment: Oh right, I completely misunderstood. Of course I need the pixel value :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

Or

textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font));
```

Comment: I really would like to use dp, and to get exactly 18dp, but I don't believe the above does that?

Answer (score 0):

You need declare text size in Dimension in `dimens.xml` in value folder and get that value and set it your `TextView` like below code.

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="text_size">18dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Get text_size from `dimens.xml` like below code:

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

//Below line returns dp value in pixel .

```
int text_size = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size);
```

Comment: 18dp is not necessarily what I want. What if x dp is only known at runtime? E.g. in code?

Comment: you need to know value of 18 dp in java code at runtime

Comment: When we get `dp` value like above code it returns a pixel value of `x dp `which we declare in dimens.xml